# How to import a config file so it can be found both by built bundle and module under Jest test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a Node project written in TypeScript which uses Rollup as a bundler and Jest as unit test framework. It has the following structure (I omitted stuff I believe it's irrelevant for the question):

```
__tests__
   greeter.test.ts
   config.json
config
   template.config.json
src
   modules
      greeter.ts
   index.ts
jest.config.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

**src/index.ts:**

```
import { greeter } from './modules/greeter'
console.log(greeter('Bojan'))
```

**src/modules/greeter.ts:**

```
const config = require('./config.json')
const greeting = config.greeting;
console.log(greeting)

export function greeter(name: string): string {
    return greeting + ", " + name
}
```

**__tests__/greeter.test.ts:**

```
import {greeter} from '../src/modules/greeter';

test('greeter uses greeting specifies in the configuration file', () => {
  expect(greeter('ABC')).toBe('hi, ABC');
});

test('greeter uses the name specified as its runtime argument', () => {
  expect(greeter('ABC')).toContain('ABC');
});
```

**jest.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    // "moduleDirectories": [
    //     "node_modules", 
    //     "<rootDir>/__tests__/"
    // ],
    // "modulePaths": [
    //     "<rootDir>/__tests__/"
    // ]
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf ./build/",
    "test": "jest --verbose --coverage --debug --env node",
    "build": "npx rollup -c",
    "start": "node ./build/app.js"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.11",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "rollup": "^1.9.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "typescript": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The idea is that build creates `app.js` bundle which reads configuration from `config.json` which should be in the same directory.

**config.json:**

```
{
    "greeting": "hi"
}
```

Bundle `app.js` contains:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
```

...and running the `app.js` works fine (when `config.json` is provided) but when I run `npm test` (or simply `npx jest`) Jest errors with:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/greeter.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module './config.json' from 'greeter.ts'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        '../src/modules/greeter.ts'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

    > 1 | const config = require('./config.json')
        |                ^
      2 | const greeting = config.greeting;
      3 | console.log(greeting)
      4 | 

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:229:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/modules/greeter.ts:1:16)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.03s
Ran all test suites.
```

To rectify this error I'd need to keep `config.json` (used for unit testing only) next to `greeter.ts` (in `src/modules`) but I'd like to keep it in `__tests__`. I tried to change *moduleDirectories* and *modulePaths* in Jest config file to no avail.

**Is there a way to make `config.json` visible to `greeter.ts` module under Jest test while maintaining its visibility from a bundle `app.js` in runtime?**

Comment: did you have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  You can't require a file that doesn't exist.

The longer answer - it's unclear to me why you'd want to do this.  Your source code should be complete, regardless of test file structure.  You wouldn't reference a file that doesn't exists, which is what you're doing when you `require('./config.json')` from `src/modules/greeter.ts` when `src/modules/config.json` does not exist.

So I'd recommend moving a copy of `config.json` into your `modules` directory, then using a `beforeAll` in your jest file, if you need the contents of `config.json` to differ for your testing purposes.

Hope this helps!